# Javascriptでウィンドが変わった瞬間、挙動が止まってしまいます

Tags: javascript

```
var kakunin=(function(){n=document.getElementsByClassName("js-validator-form");n[0].submit()}); 
setTimeout(kakunin, 2000);
$('input[value = "よろしいですか？"]').click();
```

上記コードを某サイト上で実行したところ、`setTimeout(kakunin, 2000);`まで動いで`$('input[value = "よろしいですか？"]').click();`の部分が動かなかったです。

２行目だけ手動で進んで、３行目だけ動作させたらうまく動作しました。
ウィンドウが変わった瞬間、３行目が動作しないのはなぜでしょうか？

Comment: 「ウィンドウが変わった」というのはどういう状況でしょうか。3行目のinput要素は何者でしょうか。それが click() されることで何が起きることを期待していますか。

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $('input[value = "よろしいですか？"]').click(function(){ alert('処理書いてないだけで動いてるのでは？'); }); });
```

Comment: どこに問題があり、どのように解決したか、そのコメントがなければ回答の意味がないと思います。

Comment: 他のサイトには、すでに答えしましたか、答えをコーピするのはだめですか
http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12158576392